# vue-hotel-datepicker is not working for PST — Pacific Standard Time

Tags: vue.js, datetime, vue-component, dayjs

The VueHotelPicker package is experiencing issues in US time zones, specifically when selecting check-in dates, causing the application to halt. This malfunction disrupts user experience and requires prompt resolution. Investigating compatibility with US time zones and implementing necessary adjustments are crucial to ensure seamless functionality. Seeking assistance from the package's support community or documentation may provide further insights into resolving this issue effectively. I am using the dayjs library. This is the code that I am using.

> ```
>       <client-only>
>         <HotelDatePicker
>           format="DD-MM-YYYY"
>           :alwaysVisible="false"
>           :startingDateValue="startingDate"
>           :endingDateValue="endingDate"
>           @check-in-changed="onCheckInChange"
>           @check-out-changed="onCheckOutChange"
>         />
>       </client-only>
> ```